# python combobox with return variable

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I'm trying to Tkinter with a Combox the press of a
Button to output a variable, but do not get ahead here.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk   

def select():
        name_option = var.get()
        print (Number of choices)


root = tk.Tk()


var = StringVar(root)

choices = {
    'A': '11',
    'B': '22',
    'C': '33',
    'D': '44',
    'E': '55',
}


option = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *choices)
option.place(x = 1, y = 50, width=80, height=25)

change_button = tk.Button(root, text="Klick me", command=select)

change_button.place(x = 100, y = 50, width=80, height=25)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

change

`print (Number of choices)`

to

`print(name_option)`

or just change `select()` to:

```
def select():
    print(var.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function body to:

```
def select():
        name_option = var.get()
        num = choices[name_option]
        print ("Number of choices", num)
```

I just added `num = choices[name_option]` which returns the value of the item (key) you select. And then print out `num`.